# Is 4GB of space enough for Windows 7 bootable USB flash drive?

Tags: windows, bootable-media

I am wanting to create a bootable USB flash drive, not one to install Windows from.

On my desktop, Windows once installed takes up 10GB+ of space. But on many websites it says 4GB is sufficient for a bootable USB. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

A bootable USB to install Windows 7 should be at least 4GB. However, to use Windows *entirely* off of your stick it should be at least 16GB for 32-bit or 20GB for 64-bit.

So generally it would be best to use a 32GB stick if you have one. See [this official Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/system-requirements) for the minimum Windows 7 system requirements.